# How do I make Sinon.JS callCount increment

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, sinon, chai

So I've got a Chai/Mocha/Sinon test like this:

```
import sinon from 'sinon'

describe(`My Test`, () => {
  it(`should track the number of calls`, () => {
    function testMe() {
      console.log(`test me`)
    }
    const spy = sinon.spy(testMe)
    testMe()
    console.log(spy.getCalls())
    console.log(spy.callCount)
  })
})
```

When the test runs, the following is logged:

```
test me
[]
0
```

This is baffling.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This example is too trivial to be demonstrative of an actual problem. Are you just playing around with Sinon, or is this an oversimplified example of a symptom you are seeing in real code?

Comment: The latter, but it was driving us crazy so we kept boiling it down to simpler and simpler code.  We're actually trying to test that a promise's `catch` function is actually getting called.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want spy on regular functions, the only way you can track calls to that function is by calling the *spy*:

```
it(`should track the number of calls`, () => {
  function testMe() {
    console.log(`test me`)
  }
  const spy = sinon.spy(testMe)
  spy()
  console.log(spy.getCalls())
  console.log(spy.callCount)
})
```

If `testMe` would have been a property of an object (or a method of a class), you could call the original, because in that situation Sinon can replace the original with the spied-on version. For instance:

```
describe(`My Test`, () => {
  it(`should track the number of calls`, () => {
    const obj = {
      testMe() {
        console.log(`test me`)
      }
    };
    const spy = sinon.spy(obj, 'testMe')
    obj.testMe();
    console.log(spy.callCount)
  })
})
```